# Trying to dynamically create an NSManagedObject subclass based on NSString value in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am building an application that utilizes Core Data, which has multiple entities in the Data Model.  What I would like to do is create a method which is able to create the appropriate subclass of NSManagedObject based on the name that the method it receives, which would be an NSString.

My method looks like this:

```
- (NSManagedObject *) addEntity:(NSString *)name {

  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
  NSError *error;

  //need to add a line here that casts EntityType to of type "name" which is passed into the method.
  EntityType *testEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:context];

  [context save:&error];

   return testEntity;

}
```

Where "EntityType" is of type "name", such that if I pass the name "Manager" into the method, I will create an object of type "Manager".  Therefore the above line:

```
EntityType *testEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

would read:

```
Manager *testEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

What do I need to do in order to dynamically create Entities based on the type that I pass into the method?  Please note that I am doing this because I have over twenty entities in my application and would like to have just one method that I can use for any of them.

Comment: what's the issue with your current implementation?

Comment: also don't start the method name with `new` otherwise ARC will try to release the object you create through this method

Comment: finally you are ignoring the error. You should either yield it or handle it properly.

Comment: My issue is that I find that I am trying to create a method for each entity that I have, and rather than doing that, I wish to have one method that services all of my entities.

Comment: I have also corrected the method name to "addEntity" instead of "newEntity".

Comment: ok isn't your code doing it already doing that?

Comment: No it isn't.  I need to add a line prior to: EntityType *testEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:context];  so that "EntityType" will be cast to the type "name" which is passed into the method.  I don't have an entity in my application that is literally called "EntityType".

Comment: @syedfa: Why not simply `NSManagedObject *testEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:...]` ?

Comment: @MartinR I agree, but I am wondering if it is possible to do it the way I am suggesting?  If not, I will do it this way.

Comment: @syedfa: It does not matter how `testEntity` is declared (as NSManagedObject, EntityType or Manager). `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` will always create an instance of the given subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your issue is the type of `testEntity` just use a generic `NSManagedObject`

Anyway a nice solution would be to add a category over `NSManagedObject`. Here's an implementation which basically replicates the same functionality provided by MagicalRecord.

#### NSManagedObject+Utilities.h

```
@interface NSManagedObject (Utilities)
+ (instancetype)my_createAndSave:(NSError **)error;
@end
```

---

#### NSManagedObject+Utilities.m

```
@implementation NSManagedObject (Utilities)
+ (instancetype)my_createAndSave:(NSError **)error {
    NSString *entityName = NSStringFromClass(self);
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(entityName)]) {
        entityName = [self performSelector:@selector(entityName)];
    }
    NSManagedObject *entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [self.managedObjectContext save:error];
    return entity;
}
@end
```

A few remarks:

- **Naming**:

  - being a category is always preferable to add a custom prefix, not to clash with Apple's API. I used `my_` here, but you can add whatever you like.
  - starting the method name with `new` should be reserved to method returning a non autoreleased object. Since `entity` is autoreleased, ARC will add an extra `retain` before returning the object (balanced later by a `release`) ([reference](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#explicit-method-family-control)). While this is not an issue, it breaks the standard naming conventions and should be avoided.
- **Error handling**

  - you should either yield the error or handle it properly. I chose to pass the error back to the caller in my implementation

Comment: *Methods in the `alloc`, `copy`, `mutableCopy`, and `new` families [...] implicitly return a retained object as if they were annotated with the `ns_returns_retained` attribute. This can be overridden by annotating the method with either of the `ns_returns_autoreleased` or `ns_returns_not_retained` attributes.* ([Source](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#explicit-method-family-control))

Comment: That is correct, but the ARC compiler will ensure that `newEntity` returns a (+1) retained object, by adding a `retain` call inside the method if necessary. - The naming conventions are mainly important if you mix ARC and non-ARC code.

Comment: *"When returning from such a function or method, ARC retains the value at the point of evaluation of the return statement, before leaving all local scopes."*, from the same source.