# Core Data: app crashed when accesing to NSManagedObject attribute

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I describe the problem. I have an CoreData entity "New". I'm using a fetchedResultsController with a tableView to present the objects. The problem is when app tries to update a label, it crashed (cell has two labels, but app always crashes in the same sentence, updating the same label...).

Some code here:

- That is the definition of the CoreDataManager:

{

```
// MARK: - Shared Instance

/**
*  This class variable provides an easy way to get access
*  to a shared instance of the CoreDataStackManager class.
*/
class func sharedInstance() -> CoreDataStackManager {

    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = CoreDataStackManager()
    }
    return Singleton.instance
}

// MARK: - The Core Data stack. The code has been moved, unaltered, from the AppDelegate.
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory : NSURL = {

    let urls  = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {

    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Model", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {

    let coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(SQLITE_FILE_NAME)

    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator?.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {

    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator

    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support
func saveContext() {

    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {

        managedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait {
            do {
                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
```

- Here, where the app crashes:

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HotNewsCell") as! NewsTableViewCell
      let new = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! New

      configureCell(cell, new: new)

      return cell
  }

  private func configureCell(cell: NewsTableViewCell, new: New) {

  cell.titleLabel.text = new.title
  /* Next line is where app crashes :( */
  cell.descriptionLabel.text = new.newBody

  if let url = NSURL(string: new.photoReference) {

      cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

      if new.image != nil {
          cell.imageViewNews.image = new.image
          cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
      }
      else {

          let task = NetworkRequests.sharedInstance().makeImageRequestFromURL(url) { (data, error) in

              guard error == nil else {
                  print(error)
                  return
              }

              guard let data = data else {
                  print("No data available")
                  return
              }

              let image = UIImage(data: data)
              new.image = image

              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
              {
                  cell.imageViewNews.image = image
                  cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
              }
          }

          cell.taskToCancelifCellIsReused = task
      }
  }
  ```

It's strange, because if I comment "cell.descriptionLabel.text = new.newBody", app works perfectly.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Error was EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Then, I enabled NSZombie, and the error is "message sent to deallocated instance".

Comment: App crashes how? Any error message?

Comment: exc_bad_access. After enable the NSZombie, error is: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: Double double check that `descriptionLabel` is real in your Storyboard or wherever. Is it named and connected correctly to the cell?

Comment: Yes, it's correcly connected. I use this Custom Cell in other ViewController without using CoreData and works fine... I think it's a problem of CoreData, but I don't know exactly what is the issue...

Comment: I'm new with Swift but maybe you need to unwrap the label and/or the cell?

Comment: Wrapped the cell is not the problem, because always crashes in this line. I tried to wrap the label (I change the declaration of newBody to Optional, because it is not), and still crash :(

Comment: What happens if you try `cell.descriptionLabel.text = "Test"`, do you still get the crash? That will tell you if there is a problem with the cell or with newBody.

Comment: Nope, if I put another string works fine. Only crash when I access to new.newBody attribute (and not always...)

Comment: When zombies are enabled -- what object is the deallocated instance? If it's the `New` object, show us how newBody is declared.

Comment: Try changing the `newBody` attribute name - I vaguely recall there is a problem with attributes that begin with `new....`.

Comment: I change the attribute name and it works fine apparently!! Thanks so much, I never suspect that was the problem :)

Comment: I'll add that as an answer since it is such an obscure problem and solution - it might help others.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is an artefact of using an attribute name which begins `new....`.  To avoid the problem, just change the name of the attribute.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19549527/3985749) to an unrelated question, which highlights the problem with `new...`.  From the [document](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#method-families) identified in that answer (the Clang documentation), it seems technically the problem would  not arise if the character immediately after "new" is a lower case letter.  So `newbody` would be OK, whereas `newBody` is not.  Also, for completeness, the following prefixes should likewise be avoided (though they are unlikely choices for attribute names):

- alloc
- copy
- mutableCopy
- init

Interestingly, Xcode (at least version 7.3; not sure about previous versions) will not permit these attribute names in Objective-C, giving a compiler error:

> Property follows Cocoa naming convention for returning 'owned' objects

Sadly the Swift compiler does not give any error or warning.