# Core Data - Fetch Request results not matching the predicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, magicalrecord

I'm pretty confused as to why the following is not working:

[image]

As you can see in the debug console, the value for `newerContentAvailable` is 0 even though I only want objects who have this value set to 1.  But it made its way into the results anyway.

Yes, I'm using MagicalRecord, but doubtful this has anything to do with it.    It's an old, mature codebase and `MR_findAllWithPredicate:...` just creates a fetch request on that data model and sets the predicate of the fetch.

Is there something I've not understood about Core Data?  I admit it is a beast of a framework and best practices are scarce.

Would be seriously grateful for some help!

Comment: Try changing the name of the `newerContentAvailable` attribute - I have a vague recollection that CoreData gets tripped up by attributes which begin with "new".

Comment: That seems to have fixed it!  Care to write an answer for that an I'll upvote it?

Comment: Glad that sorted it.  Bizarre, eh?  I'll add an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem may be a result of the attribute name you have used: names beginning with `new...` seem to cause some unexpected behaviour (*).  Try changing the attribute name to see if that sorts it.

(*) See for example [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36663620/3985749).

Answer (score 0):

NSNumber value of NSNumber is not substituted when used with %@ format. You have to get the intValue or floatValue (doubleValue etc) which returns the correct type.

The predicate should be,

```
NSPredicate *findPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"newerContentAvailable == 1"];
```

OR

```
NSNumber *number = @1; //Or any other number
NSPredicate *findPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"newerContentAvailable == %d", [number intValue]];
```

Comment: Nope.  Didn't work.  Plus, if I were querying the scalar type, wouldn't I put newerContentAvailableValue ?  

I've done it as in the OP for years and never a problem.  The scalar type is actually a BOOLEAN, so using @YES also didn't work.